# mi pregunta es sobre este caso sql developer

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql

Tengo un caso el cual me pide sacar un total de ventas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pidiendome el `id` del producto etc, yo hice esta query:

```
    select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'), 
       dp.idproducto,
       dp.preciounidad,
       count(p.idpedido)
       from detalle_pedido dp
       join pedido p on(dp.idpedido = p.idpedido)
       group by to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'),idproducto,preciounidad
       order by idproducto;
```

Pero me salen duplicados en el `id` y el `total de ventas` no coinciden con la imagen, aqui la bd:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias:)

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes DragonsD!!! Si pones imágenes, es bastante difícil hacer pruebas. Te recomiendo que las quites y pongas código y datos de muestra de ambas tablas.

Comment: @antonio veneroso contreras ok amigo gracias que soy nuevo xD

Comment: Estimado, te recomiendo utilizar esta página para que podamos hacer las pruebas y ayudarte http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17

Comment: si haces to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') no estas tomando datos de ningun tabla.. puede que por eso la suma de cualquier cosa.. no falta un where ahi?

Comment: Imagino que una posibilidad es que en `detallepedido` puedes tener múltiples `preciounidad`, de ahí que veas algunas filas duplicadas